# Why is my Intel i7-7800X processor overheating so quickly?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

I have a one-year-old PC with an  Intel i7-7800X processor. It has been running fine, and I am able to use it with modern stress-heavy applications and games with no problem.

Recently I've been getting temperature warnings from the OS that the processor's core temperature has reached 105 degrees (Celsius), while playing a modern game on high settings. So I installed Core Temp, and I got these results:

[image]

As you can see, the CPU loads are nowhere near high levels, yet my cores reach more than 100 degrees. Note that I had no issues before why playing the exact same game with the exact same settings.

The CPU fan is working correctly, there is no overclocking, just factory settings. All drivers are up to date.

What can cause such a behaviour? What are the risks I am taking while simply playing my game? How can I solve this problem?

---

**EDIT after solving the problem**

As others have suggested, I replaced the cooler and the thermal paste and temperatures are now back to normal. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should check if the game in question can use the GPU instead of the CPU
for its video. This might be a setting in the game, or a system-installed
video codec that needs replacement by a version that can use the GPU.

Then there are the usual causes:
Insufficient ventilation or CPU thermal paste needing renewal.

Last possibility is defective thermal sensors. If the computer is easily opened,
just open it and feel the temperature close to the CPU (touching is not
advisable).

If the PC is still under warranty, some reparations such as thermal paste renewal
and bad thermal sensors may be covered by the warranty.
It's advisable to get in contact with the manufacturer's Support in order
to get their opinion on the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you're right about the cooler/thermal paste, as the ventilator is on full power the whole time, yet it does not cool the CPU sufficiently. If I buy a new ventilator, which would be best suited for my CPU (price is not an issue)

Comment: Product recommendations are not allowed on our site. In any case, renewing the thermal paste involves reseating the CPU and is best handled by a professional. This will also probably void the warranty, so is best done via their Support.

Comment: OK thank you for your comment.

Comment: Yeah, reapplying the thermal paste would definitely be my first suggestion too. I doubt you can void warranty in this case because thermal paste will almost always last for more than 2 years before it needs to be reapplied, which would be after the warranty period has voided already. But if you never build a pc on your own, it is indeed best to let someone reapply it that has the experience.

Comment: @LPChip: Thermal paste problem within the warranty period could mean defective assembly. Some computers, mostly laptops, may have stickers that opening may void guarantee, but I agree that without such a sticker this is "probably" ok.